# How to explain coroutine in Tornado and Python?

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

I know coroutine in Python use `get = yield ret` , `callee.send()` , `callee.next()`.
But I havn't find above things such as `call.send()` in Tornado Source code *gen.py*.
How to explain coroutine in Tornado with an easy understand way? Without a **Bigger picture**, I just
can't understand what Tornado did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gen.py` **does** call `send()`, but in `Runner.run()`, not in `engine()` or `coroutine()` as you might expect.

It seems that `engine()` and `coroutine()` basically evaluate the wrapped function to see whether it returns a generator. If it does, it calls `Runner.run()` on the result, which internally seems to loop over `send()`. It's not exactly obvious what it's doing though...

Comment: I read the source code several days ago. Yes, `gen.py` calls `send()`. I missed it. It will check if a yield point is ready and set the result back to the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `send` and `next` functions are not features of Tornado, they are part of core Python. For more details see [PEP 342](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) and [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) of the official documentation.

You can write your own coroutines without tornado like so:

```
>>> def f():
...     x = 0
...     while True:
...         x = x*2
...         x = yield x
...
>>> coro = f()
>>> coro.next() #need to call 'next' once to start the coroutine
0
>>> coro.send(10)
20
>>> coro.send(100)
200
>>> coro.send(1000)
2000
>>>
```

The thing that tornado provides is an "event loop" which allows you to run a bunch of coroutines in a single process to achieve concurrency when there is blocking IO. For example in a web server that is reading data from a database and streaming the results to clients, each request will run in a separate coroutine, and tornado will handle the execution of all those coroutines concurrently by using yield/send/next at the points where IO occurs.

Comment: He's not asking what `send()` and `next()` do, he's asking how tornado works because he can't see `send()` in `gen.py` (although it is there) and this is confusing because Tornado uses yield assignment (e.g. `result = yield gen.Task(my_func)`). I came here with the same question.